# Automation/Sensors: Reading electrical switchboard press for turning lights and fans w/o relays

Tags: arduino, switches, relay, raspberry-pi, current-measurement

To reduce power consumption I am implementing a control system that uses some computer vision to validate presence in a room and eventually control the lights & fans. For comparison purpose, I want to measure power consumption before automation and I don't have an electrical meter.

How can I read the ON/OFF events (fans and lights) at the switchboard? Any specific sensors that I can use? I can always open the switchboard to use the sensors in such a case.

Comment: Is this one question or two? Are you asking how to measure power consumption without a meter? (Read the wattage of each load,  estimate the on-time and calculate kWh.) To measure on/off events at the switchboard you will have to detect changes in AC current level - assuming multiple loads are on each circuit. Best way would be to use a current clamp and logger. Look up the OpenEnergyMonitor project for Arduino based energy meter. Meanwhile, can you clarify the question?

Comment: @transistor Yes I want to ideally construct a near realtime _'time series of the energy consumption'_ for lights and fans separately **WITHOUT** using a meter. I am planning to do so, like you said, by using wattage off the manual but I need to find out the exact turn ON/OFF time. Clamp on current meter is definitely an option we thought of, but this gets really costly when monitoring multiple rooms together. Any other alternative for a large scale? Optocouplers have much lower V and I input thresholds to be used either. Also I don't know any relay coils that can handle 220V AC powerline.

Comment: You'll have no trouble getting 220V AC relays in a wide range of formats - DIN rail are easy to mount. You can also get mains voltage opto-couplers. Again, get something thats DIN-rail mountable and has finger-proof terminals. Maintain safety distance between mains and low-voltage wiring. Have a look at http://rs-online.com or http://farnell.com.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to measure power consumption before automation and I don't have an electrical meter.

So get one.  And, how is this not the obvious answer?

Power meters are relatively cheap and available.  Anything you rig up yourself would probably cost about as much, and that's not counting your time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could wire the coil / primary side of relays in <s>series</s> parallel with each of the switched loads, and the coil / secondary side normally open contacts of the relays to a digital input on your controller.

When the switches are in the ON position, current will flow through the coil, pull in the relay and close the NO contacts.  The controller will see the digital input change.

The relay's primary / coil side would have to be rated for the voltage <s>/  amperage</s> of the switched circuit.

edit - @wannabe_nerd - So, as long as the input side is rated for 220VAC you should be fine, the voltages and currents on the output side are going to be relatively tiny.

I went to the [mouser relay search tool](http://www.mouser.com/Electromechanical/Relays/_/N-5g31) and searched for 220 - 240 vac coil relays and this one came up as the most economical ice cube type at under $18 US [Phoenix Contact 2834957](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/us?urile=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=2834957)

Comment: A few problems with your answer. Unless you're thinking of a current sensing relay then relays are not wired in series with the load - they're wired in parallel. Relays don't have primaries and secondaries - they have coils and contacts. The coil has to be rated for supply voltage - the contacts for both switching current and switching voltage. Your concept concerning using a relay to monitor the loads and signal to the controller is correct.

Comment: Regarding the primary / secondary terminology, see http://media.digikey.com/pdf/other%20related%20documents/panasonic%20other%20doc/small%20signal%20relay%20techincal%20info.pdf - coil, primary, and input are synonymous; contact, secondary, and output are synonymous.

Comment: Regarding wiring in series - think about it a minute, you'll see what I am saying.  We are not using the relay to switch the load.  We are using the relay to *sense* when the "load" is switched on or off.  It is a common practice in industrial automation.

Comment: FFS I can't edit that comment, I see what you're saying, will fix the answer :)

Comment: I'm an industrial automation engineer. In your series proposal the relay coil has to pass the full current of the load which may 1 A or 100 A. No (common) relay coil can handle this range. The normal relay connection is (for AC) between live and neutral. The relay gets full mains voltage (the coil rating) and only passes enough current (mA) to ensure the contacts are energised. I see the primary / secondary reference in the Digikey reference. It's news to me - normally that's transformer terminology.

Comment: One more edit required. The coil doesn't need to be rated for the amperage of the load. The load current doesn't pass through the coil - it passes through the contacts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31824/discussion-between-batsplatsterson-and-transistor).

Comment: @batsplatsterson Thanks for your answer, I think its a good solution. I haven't found any AC input DC output relays that can handle 220V AC voltage online yet. To make it more clear, relays are completely optional (but a logical obvious choice nevertheless). Any workaround?

Comment: @wannabe_nerd - editing answer momentarily.